# Bootstrap carousel; loop using .forEach and display x many items per slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-carousel

My bootstrap carousel structure looks like this:

I'm invisioning slice to work something like this:

`final_push.push(items.image_urls.slice(0,5))` # I use the following code to get every 5 items per slide. As of now it doesn't do that instead it creates 3 slides with one image on first slide, 2 images on second slide and 3 images on the third slide.

```
var new_html = `    
        <div id="myCarousel`+current_index+`" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">var image_collection = '' # empty
```

variable which I later append with column divs.

```
var row = 0


final_push[0].forEach(function(results)
{

    row++
    image_collection += `<div style='margin-left:12%;' onclick = 
     "setMainImage('`+results+`')" style="display:inline-block;max-
      width:100%; width:20%;max-height: 20%;" class="col-sm-2"><img  
      style=" border-radius: 8px; height:100px;" src="`+results+`"  
     class="img-responsive" alt="test1">
                                                     </div>`
    if(row == 1){
     new_html += `<div class="item active"><div class="row">`
     new_html += image_collection

    }else{
        new_html += `<div class="item"><div class="row">`
        new_html += image_collection
    }
    new_html +=`
       </div>
    </div>`

new_html +=`
    </div>
       <a style="color:blue; font-size:3.0vw;" class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel`+current_index+`" data-slide="prev"> ‹
        </a>

      <a style="color:blue; font-size:3.0vw;" class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel`+current_index+`" data-interval="false"  data-slide="next">›
       </a>
  </div>`
```

The above code compiles to a proper carousel with messed up loop indexing.

My goal was to show 3 items per slide.

My tactic was to build rows as my slide; and columns as my items in grid. 
It didn't seem to work.
I'm also not slicing correctly; I think. This is what my current screen looks like:

**FIRST GRID LOOKS LIKE THIS**
[image: FIRST GRID SLIDE LOOKS LIKE THIS]

**SECOND GRID LOOKS LIKE THIS**
[image: SECOND GRID SLIDE LOOKS LIKE THIS]

**THIRD GRID LOOKS LIKE THIS**
[image: THIRD GRID SLIDE LOOKS LIKE THIS]

This also; doesn't loop farther than 3rd items in my array; for instance, I have an array of image URLS.

['imgurl1', 'imgurl2', 'imgurl3','imgUrl4', 'imgUrl5', 'imgUrl6']

^ That's the type of data I get from `items.image_urls`
The following array should create 2 slides with 3 items per slide.

Right now; mine doesn't do anything; I have a feeling I'm doing something really wrong. Since I'm building HTML using JS it looks really messy; apologies about that.